# What is the best way to connect some street corners with electricity cables using graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

A company wants to place vending machines at some (not all) corners of a street network.  They need to find the best way to connect them all to electricity, knowing that electricity cables can only be placed along streets and that the price is proportional to the distance. What is the correct way to solve this via graph theory?

Note that

1. Bindings can be done either at the vending machines or at any street corner
2. The distance between two consecutive corners is weighted (i.e. the streets aren't all perpendicular/parallel and at identical distance from each other)

I'm guessing it has to do with finding the minimal spanning tree but it's not directly applicable since all the nodes are not concerned...?

Comment: So you want to minimize the total cabling distance? Or the total amount of vending machines?

Comment: Minimise the cabling distance.

Comment: In that case I see it as a minimum spanning tree as you do, and all nodes will be concerned.

Comment: No, because the vending machines are not at all corners

Comment: What do you mean, thy are not at all corners. Is this an additional constraint? If it is not forbidden, one solution is to place vending machines at each corner.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in the problem statement. The place of the machines is already chosen, and its on some arbitrary corners. The only question is how to do the wiring.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding dummy vending machines on the nodes where there aren't any, then finding the minimum spanning tree?

Once you have it, delete the dummy machines.