# Finding path-network such that each connected component contains certain points

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, optimization, connectedness, network

So I'm currently working on a geometric optimization problem and came upon a graph-problem where I am struggling to find a solution.

**Edit:**

So let $\{x_i\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\{y_j\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $i = 1,..., n$ and $j = 1,...,m$. Furthermore for each pair of points $(a, b) \in (\{x_i\}_i\cup \{y_j\}_j) \times (\{x_i\}_i\cup \{y_j\}_j)$ the distance $d(a, b)$ is known. The distance $d$ might be unequal to the euclidean distance. Now I would like to find the minimal path or network of paths such that each $x_i$ is connected to at least one $y_j$ or to be more precise, the **problem** is:

Find the (undirected, not necessarily connected) graph (V, E) such that $V = \{x_i\}_i \cup \{y_j\}_j$ and following conditions hold:

1. Each connected component contains at least one $y_j$.
2. For each $y_j$ exists at least one $x_i$ connected to it.
3. The total sum of edge-length gets minimized, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^l length(E_k) \rightarrow min$ with $E = {E_1,..., E_l}$ where the the length of a edge $E_k$ is the distance $d(a, b)$ between its respective nodes $a, b$.

There may be obstacles in the way between some pairs $(x_i, x_j)$ so not all possible edges have the same length, i.e. are weighted.

To give some motivation for this problem:
Imagine the $x_i$ are entries to houses which are all inside some domain $G$ and on the boundary of the domain $\partial G$ lie the possible entries $y_j$ to the domain. Now I want to construct a admissible street network such that each house is connected to the boundary, i.e. every person living in some house in this domain can actually leave the domain on a street.

I'm currently a bit lost here. One could try to compute by brute force the correct graph but this sounds like madness, especially as this is part of a bigger computation called more than once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Best regards,
PlumBum

**Edit 2:**
This is a sort of minimum spanning tree problem, somewhat similar to this [What is the best way to connect some street corners with electricity cables using graph theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1603486/744138). But in this case I allow for several connected-components if certain constraints are fulfilled (to be precise when the boundary is connected to the inside).

Comment: Suppose $n  \leq m$.  Connect each $x_i$ to $y_i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$.  You didn't get all the rest of the $y_i$s for $n <i \leq m$, so connect each one to $x_1$.  Why doesn't this work?  (I'm trying to understand your question.)  Do the obvious reversal if $n > m$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I wasn't clear in the question. The point is that the the length of the graph should be minimized. I will edit the question to clearify

Comment: And in some cases your ansatz wouldn't give the optimal solution as one might need to connect each $x_i$ to some $y_j$ and therefore would have a path through the entire domain. In this case it might be better to connect some of the $x_i$ to each other and afterwards connect those already connected parts to the boundary-points $y_j$.